# How can I solve my code error when use pointer for char

Tags: c, pointers

I got warning when I try to compile, I can not solve this problem. Could you guys please help me. Thank you.

> warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   [-Wint-conversion]    char ch = NULL;
>                ^

And here my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "order.h"
void readInts(int* ptr1, int*ptr2, int*ptr3, char* ptrChar);

int main(void)
{
    int p1, p2, p3;
    char ch == NULL;
    readInts(&p1, &p2, &p3, &ch);

    if (ch == 'A')
    {
    printf("%s\n", "Ascending3");
    printf("%s %d %d %d\n", "Before swap: ", p1, p2, p3);
    ascending3(&p1, &p2, &p3);
    printf("%s %d %d %d\n\n", "After: ", p1, p2, p3);
    }
    else if (ch =='B')
    {
    printf("%s\n", "Descending3");
    printf("%s %d %d %d\n", "Before swap: ", p1, p2, p3);
    descending3(&p1, &p2, &p3);
    printf("%s %d %d %d\n\n", "After swap: ", p1, p2, p3);
    }
    return 0;
}

void readInts(int* ptr1, int* ptr2, int* ptr3, char* ptrChar)
{
    printf("%s\n", "Enter 3 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", ptr1, ptr2, ptr3);
    printf("%s\n", "Enter a character A&B");
    scanf(" %c", ptrChar);
}
```

Comment: What do you think the declaration `char ch == NULL;` do? What is the difference between null character and `NULL` pointer?

Comment: `char ch == NULL;` (`==` typo as `=`)--> `char ch = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that it expects NULL to be assigned to a pointer type. You are assigning NULL to a character, not a character pointer. So, it is implicitly converting the NULL pointer to a 0 integer before assigning it to the character ch.

It is warning you that this is probably not what you intended and you should examine the code. In your case, you probably want to just assign 0 to the character.

```
char ch = 0;
```

Comment: Or, better, `char ch = '\0';`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point. Your '\0' literal will have the type char, at least in a conforming C++ compiler. So that will, technically, have a more appropriate type. However, since the question is tagged "c" and we are being pedantic here, a character literal has the type int in plain old C. So, if you are using  a C compiler, '\0' and 0 are exactly the same thing. You may want to use the character literal notation to remind yourself, and future readers of the code, that the value is indeed a character, but I'd prefer to just skip the extraneous 3 keystrokes.